# How to get a filtered list

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
      listeTagGr.DataContext = From a In oo.articles
                              Where a.producttype.id.Equals(1)
                              Select a.tagstrings Distinct
```

Error  : tagstrings is a list.
I wan't to retrieve the list of distincts tagstrings for articles where producttype is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  listeTagGr.DataContext = (From a In oo.articles
                            Where a.producttype.id.Equals(1)
                            From ts in a.tagstrings
                            Select ts).Distinct()
```